# I want to pass HTML form fields to powershell variables in a script

Tags: html, jquery-ui, powershell-3.0

Basically iam trying to pass the form field information which has been inputted in the browser to the variables in the powershell, Just want some random ideas how to perform it and sample scripts or ideas

Answer (score 0):

On the forms onSubmit() function you could attach some logic that writes the form fields to a locally saved .CSV file. Then you could parse the .CSV into powershell variables and do your stuff.

Comment: onSubmit() is a JS function i believe but do you have sample type where the Form is being saved in CSV, Even xml does the job for me !!

Comment: Ok. So this job consists of two things. First we have to make the form in HTML, we set the HTML to do some type of action on submit. When you submit the form, it also brings the formdata to the handler.
Here is an example of how that would work on a Node server. 
https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190
For a php server it would look different, but same logic. 

In the function that handles the form data, you must add some kind of logic that takes the form data and saves it.

Comment: Once you have established a function that gets the form data from your javascript on your server, you just need to convert the JSON formdata you get to a XML or CSV saved as a file. You have many options for doing this, here is one of them that works for a Node server: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer
or
https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-xml
and for php
https://www.regur.net/decode/creation-xml-file-php-simplexml/